# Problems converting a C header to D

Tags: mysql, c, d

I'm trying to translating the MySql C connector 6.02 headers to D, but I get some weird crashes.
My guess is I've made some mistakes on translating the structs or function (I'm not very good at C).

I used implib /system on the libmysql.dll to create a lib file.

I couldn't get htod.exe to work. Using -hs (include system files) complained it couldn't find system files.

Coffimplib.exe didn't have an option to prepend _ to exported internal names.

I couldn't find a free version of coff2omf.

mysql.d is the wrapper. I've included the C definition before each wrapped definition to easier spot bugs. The file includes the mysql dll and converted libfile too.

When compiling mytest_fails.d it crashes. mytest_works.d only has an assert, and this makes it work.. Compiling mytest_works with -release makes it crash too.

I've been using dmd 2.051

[Download mytest.zip from share1t.com](http://share1t.com/mokw0l)

**Update:** I've also asked some question regarding this on the D.learn newsgroup, but I don't think anyone has gone through the code.

- [C Const](http://www.digitalmars.com/webnews/newsgroups.php?art_group=digitalmars.D.learn&article_id=25308)
- [Compiler extensions](http://www.digitalmars.com/webnews/newsgroups.php?art_group=digitalmars.D.learn&article_id=25310)
- [Connot get htod.exe to work](http://www.digitalmars.com/webnews/newsgroups.php?art_group=digitalmars.D.learn&article_id=25324)
- [The weird crashes](http://www.digitalmars.com/webnews/newsgroups.php?art_group=digitalmars.D.learn&article_id=25150)

Comment: Also note that htod happily drops constness and stuff that is deactivated by the preprocessor (i.e. #if VERFOO ... isn't translated to version(VERFOO)...)

You might also try SWIG or http://dsource.org/projects/visuald/browser/trunk/c2d to convert C headers.

Comment: @Trass3r: I forgot to mention that, but swig just crashed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**stdcall** is a Windows function calling convention (very different from the C calling convention). HTOD failed to mark several functions with **extern(Windows)**. This is normal, since HTOD isn't equipped to handle macros (**STDCALL** is defined as a macro, I can see that from the leftover comments in msyql.d).

Here's an updated mysql.d file:
http://dl.dropbox.com/u/9218759/mysql.d

Now, you need the proper import library in OMF format. I'd generally advise that you do not use implib for this. I've had several problems with it and others have reported having problems using it. Using **coffimplib** is the way to go. But first, you will need a COFF import library.

If you need it, the Mysql release with the COFF import library can be downloaded from here: http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/mirror.php?id=377977#mirrors (Libraries in DLL form marked for Visual Studio usually come with a COFF import library).

But I'm providing you the translated COFF import library in OMF format here: http://dl.dropbox.com/u/9218759/libmysql.lib

I've tried both of your test cases and they both seem to work fine now. In case of problems, try to check the translated header file again (mysql.d), it's possible that I might have missed to specify all the calling conventions properly.

Comment: Thanks! I couldn't get htod to work, so this is solely my failure. I'll your solution today or tomorrow. Btw. How did you create the OMF library? Have you bought coff2omf? Or do you have another tool?

Comment: You can find coffimplib here: http://www.digitalmars.com/d/archives/c++/announce/864.html

Comment: Thanks a million. Worked like a charm. I still encounter some strange things, but that might be just some unclear documentation from mysql.

Comment: Your dropbox link gives me a 404, any chance you could put it back up there?